# Get the value out of Just constructor

Tags: haskell

I am trying to print only the monad value and not the context information in ghci,

```
ghci> let a = Just 10
ghci> print !!!!!!
```

!!!!! must print,

```
10
```

and not

```
Just 10
```

Comment: And what should happen for the case that `a` actually contains `Nothing`?

Comment: yes, it is a duplicate...

Comment: Not mentioned in the dupe, since the dupe was not about monadic things: `traverse print` will do.

Comment: @DanielWagner Or better, `traverse_ print` to avoid confusion in ghci.

Comment: Prelude> import Data.Maybe
    Prelude Data.Maybe> let a = Just 10
    Prelude Data.Maybe> print $ fromJust a
    10

Comment: Beware of `fromJust`: `Prelude> import Data.Maybe; Prelude Data.Maybe> let a = Nothing; Prelude Data.Maybe> print $ fromJust a -- *boom*`